# Screen orientation change forces data re-entry

Tags: android, orientation, android-edittext

I'm developing a simple app, only a handful of activities and nothing to complicated.  The issue I'm having is that in a few of my activities I have EditText widgets, and when the screen is rotated, these widgets loose their values.  They still visually, that is, on the handset screen, report their values from before the rotation, but to the code report their default values.

An example, I have an activity with an EditText, I enter a number, 15, the calculator starts calculating, displays a result.  If at this point I rotate to a different orientation, as expected the activity dies, reloads, shows the new orientation, my value of 15 is still in the EditText, however the calculator (the code) calculates as if it was 0, which is the initial value.  I have not tried changing the initial value to see if it is really pulling from the default value, or just setting itself to 0 when I cast it as an int.

If I didn't explain this well enough, let me know, I can add source code if I need to.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you handling the orientation change, or is it just going through the default destroy->restart cycle? (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) for some info on this if you need it)

Comment: I am just going through the default cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When are you reading the values? View state is preserved by `Activity`'s default implementation of `onRestoreInstanceState`, which happens between `onStart` and `onPostCreate`. If you are reading the values before this happens, that would explain why you are seeing default values for your calculation rather than the values that are displayed once the screen is drawn.

Comment: I know I read that in the Docs 100 times yesterday, but it didn't click until you said it.  I moved my Calc code into onPostCreate, and it works great.  Man if that was a snake....